# How to make array in object while parsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am parsing the JSON object. I want to set value which is stored in session against id. I have this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "text": "a",
    "icon": true,
    "li_attr": {
      "id": "a"
    },
    "a_attr": {
      "href": "#"
    },
    "state": {
      "loaded": true,
      "opened": false,
      "selected": false,
      "disabled": false
    },
    "data": {

    },
    "children": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "text": "b\n            ",
    "icon": true,
    "li_attr": {
      "id": "b"
    },
    "a_attr": {
      "href": "#"
    },
    "state": {
      "loaded": true,
      "opened": false,
      "selected": false,
      "disabled": false
    },
    "data": {

    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "b-a-1",
        "text": "b-a",
        "icon": true,
        "li_attr": {
          "id": "b-a-1"
        },
        "a_attr": {
          "href": "#"
        },
        "state": {
          "loaded": true,
          "opened": false,
          "selected": false,
          "disabled": false
        },
        "data": {

        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "b-b-2",
        "text": "b-b\n                    ",
        "icon": true,
        "li_attr": {
          "id": "b-b-2"
        },
        "a_attr": {
          "href": "#"
        },
        "state": {
          "loaded": true,
          "opened": false,
          "selected": false,
          "disabled": false
        },
        "data": {

        },
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "b-b-a",
            "text": "b-b-a",
            "icon": true,
            "li_attr": {
              "id": "b-b-a"
            },
            "a_attr": {
              "href": "#"
            },
            "state": {
              "loaded": true,
              "opened": false,
              "selected": false,
              "disabled": false
            },
            "data": {

            },
            "children": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "b-b-b",
            "text": "b-b-b",
            "icon": true,
            "li_attr": {
              "id": "b-b-b"
            },
            "a_attr": {
              "href": "#"
            },
            "state": {
              "loaded": true,
              "opened": false,
              "selected": false,
              "disabled": false
            },
            "data": {

            },
            "children": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "c-1",
    "text": "c\n            ",
    "icon": true,
    "li_attr": {
      "id": "c-1"
    },
    "a_attr": {
      "href": "#"
    },
    "state": {
      "loaded": true,
      "opened": false,
      "selected": false,
      "disabled": false
    },
    "data": {

    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "not-c-a-1",
        "text": "c-a",
        "icon": true,
        "li_attr": {
          "id": "not-c-a-1"
        },
        "a_attr": {
          "href": "#"
        },
        "state": {
          "loaded": true,
          "opened": false,
          "selected": false,
          "disabled": false
        },
        "data": {

        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "not-c-b-2",
        "text": "b-b",
        "icon": true,
        "li_attr": {
          "id": "not-c-b-2"
        },
        "a_attr": {
          "href": "#"
        },
        "state": {
          "loaded": true,
          "opened": false,
          "selected": false,
          "disabled": false
        },
        "data": {

        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to make same type array having object. Inside the object there might be possibility of nested objects. I just want to set value against it id.

Can we get the information of children? If there are children, I need to set value. Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/91/

```
$('#json').click(function(){
 var json_list=$('#tree').jstree(true).get_json(); console.log(json_list.length);
    for(var i=0;i<json_list.length;i++){
        var obj={};
        alert(json_list[i].id)
        obj=sessionStorage.getItem(json_list[i].id);
        arr[i]=obj;
    }

console.log(arr)

})
});
```

Expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "a": "value_a",

    "arr": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "b": "value_b",

    "arr": [
      {
        "b-a-1": "value_b-a-1",

        "arr": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "b-b-1": "value_b-b-2",

        "arr": [
          {
            "b-b-a": "value_b-b-a",

            "arr": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "b-b-b": "value_b-b-b",

            "arr": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "c-1": "value_c-1",

    "arr": [
      {
        "not-c-a-1": "value_not-c-a-1",

        "arr": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "not-c-b-2": "value_not-c-b-2",

        "arr": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make any sense to me. Sometimes you have `arr` and `children`. Sometimes `arr` is an array and sometimes it's a string. You will need a better explanation of the kind of transformations you are trying to achieve. You should just give a simple example of **1** initial node with children and how that node should be transformed. Also just include relevant properties.

Comment: @plalx sorry please check my update.Sorry .. it is an "arr" not children I will update my question

Comment: arr is always array not string ..I just make own ..it simply same as original just change name from children to arr

Comment: I just get value from session and but on the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a reviver function that you pass to `JSON.parse`.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq2Df/1/)

```
var json = JSON.stringify([{ id: 'root', children: [ { id: 'nested' } ]}]);

var p = JSON.parse(json, function (k, v) {
    if (!k) return v;
    if (k === 'id' || k === 'children') return v;
    if (+k == k && typeof v === 'object' && v != null && 'id' in v) {
        v[v.id] = 'value_' + v.id;
        delete v.id;
        if (v.children) v.arr = v.children;
        delete v.children;
        return v;
    }
});

JSON.stringify(p); //[{"root":"value_root","arr":[{"nested":"value_nested"}]}]
```

EDIT: I tried to make the code more robust by using a different approach, but it did not work as expected because the `children` key did not always came before we started to iterate over the array. Have a look at the edit history, perhaps I overlooked something.

Comment: can you please give fiddle

Comment: @user944513 I edited the answer and provided a fiddle. While the code is definitely more complex, this transforms the structure **while parsing** rather than the other solution that transforms it after parsing.

Comment: @plax can you look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582173/how-to-validate-form-which-is-prepared-dynamically-using-dfom-plugin

Comment: @user944513 I tried to avoid these wierd conditionnals to make the function more robust (e.g. will not work well if you have multiple arrays), but somehow `JSON.parse` did not seem to be consistent in it's iteration. Have a look at the edited version of this answser in the history. Perhaps I overlooked something.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `"b-b-1": "value_b-b-2"` in the expected output is a type and really should be `"b-b-2": "value_b-b-2"` it should be very easy to map the original array to the expected output.

Use the `map` method on arrays (or, if you need to support older browsers, use the `map` implementation of some library you are using (e.g. jQuery or Underscore).

For each of the items in your array, you need to create an item which has two properties. The first property should be named according to the value of the `id` property of the input object and the value of the property seems like it should be the literal `value_` followed by the value of the `id` property from the input object.

Furthermore, each item should also have an `arr` property, which is the result of applying our item mapping function to the items in the `children` array.

So the code could look something like

```
function mapItem(inputItem){
    var item = {};
    item[inputItem.id] = "value_" + inputItem.id;
    item.arr = inputItem.children.map(mapItem);
    return item;
};
var results = originalArray.map(mapItem);
```

I have the above mapping function running against your sample data at http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Kq/

Comment: I thought the OP wanted **while parsing**. That's after parsing.

Comment: @robert can you look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582173/how-to-validate-form-which-is-prepared-dynamically-using-dfom-plugin

Comment: @plalx You are absolutely correct that the title of the question says 'while parsing'. I do, however, consider the `map` approach a lot easier to read and the array would have to be _very_ large before I would try to optimize the performance of the code by doing it at the moment of parsing. It is good than, that we provide two different suggestions on how to solve OP's problem so that OP can choose.

Comment: @plalx I do admit that I missed the part about 'while parsing' when I wrote my own answer, which is why I have upvoted yours. I still, however, think that the array would have to be very large before I would go into doing the mapping as part of the parsing instead of keeping them separate.