# how to validate form which is prepared dynamically using dfom plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

can you please tell me how to validate form which is prepared dynamically using dfom plugin?
I used jquery validation but it don't work on chrome.
can you please tell me why dform with jquery validation not working in chrome ?.It is working fine in firefox but not with in chrome why ?? Here is http://jsfiddle.net/8bweG/13/?

```
$("#sform").dform(
 {
  "elements": [
    {
      "html": [
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "id": "totalRetryCount",
              "name": "totalRetryCount",
              "required": false,
              "value": 0,
              "tabindex": 1,
              "validate": {
                  "messages": {
                    "number": "Naveen Kanjush hain"
                  }
              }
            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Total Retry Count"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "id": "totalRepeatCount",
              "name": "totalRepeatCount",
              "required": false,
              "value": 0,
              "tabindex": 2,
              "validate": {
                  "messages": {
                    "number": "Naveen Kanjush hain"
                  }
              }
            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Total Repeat Count"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "select",
              "options": {
                "true": "true",
                "false": "false"
              },
              "id": "summaryReportRequired",
              "name": "summaryReportRequired",
              "required": false,
              "value": "true",
              "tabindex": 3,

            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Summary Report Required"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "select",
              "options": {
                "ALWAYS": "ALWAYS",
                "ON_SUCCESS": "ON_SUCCESS"
              },
              "id": "postConditionExecution",
              "name": "postConditionExecution",
              "required": false,
              "value": "ON_SUCCESS",
              "tabindex": 4,

            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Post Condition Execution"
        }
      ],
      "type": "div",
      "class": "inputDiv",
      "caption": "<h3>Configuration Parameters</h3>"
    }
  ],
  "id": "testSuiteConfigurationform",
  "name": "testSuiteConfigurationform",
  "method": "post"
}
);
```

Problem is that 
First field of type ="number".User only type number in that .If user type string or character and move to another field it gives error.if you check on firefox this fiddle it is giving validation error .But on chrome and safari same functionality not work.
please follow these steps

on first field write "abc" then click below or next field.it gives error front of first field.it is display on firefox but not on chrome

Comment: I don't understand, what should your code do and what is doing?

Comment: it is making dynamically forum using dform plugin

Comment: That is great. But what is not working?

Comment: Please check external resource of fiddle

Comment: validation .It is working on firefox .but not in chrome and safari

Comment: What do you mean with *validation*? BTW, if you want that I read [this](http://i.imgur.com/JOTM8xo.png), you are going to wait forever. Explain it with your words, add more explanation in your question.

Comment: you can write any thing in text field other than number it should give error but it is not giving

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52437/discussion-between-user3530755-and-lucio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working but you are missing the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button.

This is the correct version: http://jsfiddle.net/8bweG/22/

```
$("#sform").dform({
    "action" : "http://dgg.gg",
    "method" : "get",
  "elements": [
    {
      "html": [
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "id": "totalRetryCount",
              "name": "totalRetryCount",
              "required": false,
              "value": 0,
              "tabindex": 1,
              "validate": {
                  "messages": {
                    "number": "Naveen Kanjush hain"
                  }
              }
            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Total Retry Count"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "id": "totalRepeatCount",
              "name": "totalRepeatCount",
              "required": false,
              "value": 0,
              "tabindex": 2,
              "validate": {
                  "messages": {
                    "number": "Naveen Kanjush hain"
                  }
              }
            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Total Repeat Count"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "select",
              "options": {
                "true": "true",
                "false": "false"
              },
              "id": "summaryReportRequired",
              "name": "summaryReportRequired",
              "required": false,
              "value": "true",
              "tabindex": 3,

            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Summary Report Required"
        },
        {
          "html": [
            {
              "type": "select",
              "options": {
                "ALWAYS": "ALWAYS",
                "ON_SUCCESS": "ON_SUCCESS"
              },
              "id": "postConditionExecution",
              "name": "postConditionExecution",
              "required": false,
              "value": "ON_SUCCESS",
              "tabindex": 4,

            }
          ],
          "type": "fieldset",
          "caption": "Post Condition Execution"
        },
        {
            "html": [
                {
                    "type" : "submit",
                    "value" : "Login"
                }
            ],
            "type": "fieldset",
            "caption": "Go away"
        }
      ],
      "type": "div",
      "class": "inputDiv",
      "caption": "<h3>Configuration Parameters</h3>"
    }
  ],
  "id": "testSuiteConfigurationform",
  "name": "testSuiteConfigurationform",
  "method": "post"
}
);
```